# C++: std::getline() returns empty std::string when reading non-empty line of a file

Tags: c++, std, ifstream, getline

I have a poll-class which needs to be able to save itself in a file and load it again. Everything works except for one call of `getline(ifile, lineBuffer)` in the implementation of `loadPoll`. (Marked with "<==========="). It should read the 9th line of the example file into *lineBuffer* however my debugger shows the string to be empty in this case only. On all other calls of `getline()` it reads the correct line. What am I doing wrong?

This is the mo_poll class and pollOption struct:

```
typedef struct{
    int id;
    int voteCount = 0;
    std::string value;
    std::vector<std::string> voterIDs;

    bool opt_hasVoted(const std::string& voterID);

}pollOption;

class mo_poll
{
public:
    //unrelated constructors and methods

    void loadPoll(const std::string& filePath);
    void savePoll(const std::string& filePath);

    std::string topic;
    std::vector<pollOption> options;

    //data
    std::string author = "";
    std::string pollChannelID = "";
    std::string pollMessageID = "";
    bool isSaved = false;
    bool messageExists = false;
    bool isClosed = false;
    bool allowCustOpt = false;
    bool allowMultipleChoice = false;
private:
    int nextID = 1;
};
```

The *loadPoll()* method is defined like this:

```
void mo_poll::loadPoll(const std::string &filePath){
    std::ifstream ifile;
    ifile.open(filePath);
    if(!ifile.is_open()){return;}

    //Topic:
    std::string lineBuffer;
    getline(ifile, lineBuffer);
    lineBuffer.erase(lineBuffer.begin());//Remove "'"
    lineBuffer.pop_back();//Remove last "'"
    topic = lineBuffer;
    //Author:
    getline(ifile, lineBuffer);
    lineBuffer.erase(lineBuffer.begin());//Remove "'"
    lineBuffer.pop_back();//Remove last "'"
    author = lineBuffer;
    //pollChannelID:
    getline(ifile, lineBuffer);
    pollChannelID = lineBuffer;
    //pollMessageID:
    getline(ifile, lineBuffer);
    pollMessageID = lineBuffer;
    //messageExists:
    getline(ifile, lineBuffer);
    messageExists = intToBool(std::stoi(lineBuffer));
    //isClosed:
    getline(ifile, lineBuffer);
    isClosed = intToBool(std::stoi(lineBuffer));
    //allowCustOpt:
    getline(ifile, lineBuffer);
    allowCustOpt = intToBool(std::stoi(lineBuffer));
    //allowMultipleChoice:
    getline(ifile, lineBuffer);
    allowMultipleChoice = intToBool(std::stoi(lineBuffer));
    //First explicitly saved optionID:
    getline(ifile, lineBuffer);
    int lastOptID = std::stoi(lineBuffer);

    //Load all options data:
    bool firstLineOfOption = true;
    while(!ifile.eof()){
        getline(ifile, lineBuffer);//'lineBuffer' is empty but it shouldn't <=============
        if(lineBuffer.size() > 0){
            //Get optionID and values:
            std::regex idReg("\\d+");
            int currOptID = std::stoi(returnMatches(lineBuffer, idReg)[0]);
            std::regex valReg("'.+'");
            auto vals = returnMatches(lineBuffer, valReg);
            std::string currOptValue = vals[0];
            currOptValue.erase(currOptValue.begin());
            currOptValue.pop_back();
            pollOption currOption;
            if(currOptID == lastOptID){
                currOption.id = currOptID;
                if(firstLineOfOption){
                    currOption.value = currOptValue;
                    firstLineOfOption = false;
                }else{
                    currOption.voterIDs.push_back(currOptValue);
                }
            }
            else{
                firstLineOfOption = true;
                options.push_back(currOption);
                currOption = pollOption();//Empty currOption
            }
        }
    }
    ifile.close();
}
```

Here is an example file:

```
'Test Poll'
'Some_Author_Name'
123456789012345678
123456789012345678
1
0
0
1
1
o 1 'Yes.'
o 2 'No'
o 2 '123456789012345678'
o 3 'Maybe'
o 4 'Something else'
o 4 '123456789012345678'
```

Comment: TL;DR of the dupe: Change `while(!ifile.eof()){
        getline(ifile, lineBuffer);` to `while(getline(ifile, lineBuffer)){` so that your read operation controls the loop.  Without that, you get an extra read of the file with it being empty.

Comment: That was the problem, thanks!